# Separate message for condition in vb document

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am  creating a seat booking system in visual basic for coursework and it has to allow users to book seats from rows A to E. For row B, I have set it so that there are no seats remaining, however the message simply tells the user that there are not enough seats and that the maximum available seats is 0. I need the code to tell users that there are no seats remaining. My code is as follows:
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim rowNumber As Integer
    Dim SeatsData As String(,) = {{"booked", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10"},
                                  {"booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked"},
                                  {"C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10"},
                                  {"D1", "booked", "booked", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10"},
                                  {"E1", "E2", "booked", "booked", "booked", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "E10"}}

    If ListBox2.Text = "A" Then
        rowNumber = 0
    ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "B" Then
        rowNumber = 1
    ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "C" Then
        rowNumber = 2
    ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "D" Then
        rowNumber = 3
    ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "E" Then
        rowNumber = 4
    End If

    FindSeats(rowNumber, ListBox1.Text, SeatsData)

End Sub
Function FindSeats(ByVal RowNumber As Integer, ByVal NumSeats As Integer, SeatsData As Array) As String

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim arrayPos As Integer = 0
    Dim maxSeats As Integer = 0
    Dim FirstSeat As String = 0
    Dim LastSeat As String = 0
    Dim Seatsfound As Boolean = False
    Dim returnMsg As String = ""

    Do While Seatsfound = False
        Dim seatChar As String = SeatsData(RowNumber, arrayPos)
        arrayPos = arrayPos + 1

        If seatChar = "booked" Then
            i = 0
        Else
            If i = 0 Then
                FirstSeat = seatChar
            End If
            i = i + 1

            If i > maxSeats Then
                maxSeats = i
            End If

        End If

        If i = NumSeats Then
            LastSeat = seatChar
            If FirstSeat = LastSeat Then
                returnMsg = "Found seat: " + FirstSeat
            Else
                returnMsg = "Found seats: " + FirstSeat + " - " + LastSeat
            End If
            MsgBox(returnMsg)
            Label3.Text = returnMsg
            Seatsfound = True
            Exit Do
        End If

        If arrayPos = 10 Then
            returnMsg = "Not enough available seats, maximum available seats: " + CStr(maxSeats)
            MsgBox(returnMsg)
            Label3.Text = returnMsg
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Function
End Class
```

How can I set my code so that it tells the user "there are no remaining seats in this row" or something?

Comment: Sounds like an *excellent* opportunity to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: A `dictionary<string, List<string>>` will make your life less miserable here

Comment: A custom class would be a good way with a collection of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a custom class to design your problem domain, a simple approach is using a Dictionary

For example

```
Sub Main
    Dim seats = new Dictionary(Of string, List(Of String))()
    seats.Add("A", new List(Of String) FROM {"A1", "A2", "A3"})
    seats.Add("B", new List(Of String) FROM {"booked", "booked", "booked"})
    seats.Add("C", new List(Of String) FROM {"C1", "C2", "booked"})
    seats.Add("D", new List(Of String) FROM {"booked", "booked", "D3"})


    Dim result = FindSeat(seats, "D")
    Console.WriteLine(result)  ' Output = D3

    result = FindSeat(seats, "B")
    Console.WriteLine(result)  ' Output = "No free seat on that line"

End Sub


Function FindSeat(seats as Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)), line as String) As String

    if seats.ContainsKey(line) Then
        dim seatLine = seats(line)
        Dim placeFree = seatLine.FirstOrDefault(Function (x) x <> "booked")
        if placeFree Is Nothing then
            return "No free seat on that line"
        else
            return placeFree
        End If
    Else
       return "Not a valid line letter"
    End If
End Function
```

In `Main`, I have statically declared a Dictionary that contains as `Key` the line letter while a `List(Of String)` is used as value to declare the seats names and their current state.

Now to find a free seat I get the `List(Of String)` corresponding to the Line letter and the apply a simple FirstOrDefault to get the first seat not booked

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where would I place this in my code? I'm very new to VB and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it!

Comment: A Dictionary is a data structure with a sequence of unique Keys and Values. In your context the Key is the RowLetter while the Values are the Seats of that row. So, you change your array SeatsData with this dictionary. You initialize the Dictionary as you wish (static data, reading from file or database but this is another matter) then you replace your FindSeat with the one provided above and pass the parameters required to find your free Seat,

Comment: I am getting a build error, i have simply copy and pasted this at the bottom of my existing code (within the same class) and it says that the local variable 'result' has already been declared in the current block? I am assuming this is in reference to these lines:

Comment: Dim result = FindSeat(seats, "D")
        Console.WriteLine(result)  ' Output = D3

        Dim result = FindSeat(seats, "B")
        Console.WriteLine(result)  ' Output = "No free seat on that line"

Comment: Ignore those, I placed this code into the wrong document by mistake.

Comment: Yes result declared twice is my fault, fixed

Comment: Ah thank you, however I'm still a bit muddled as to where to insert this into my code?

Comment: That depends on the logic of your program. As now it is useless becase everytime you click the button you set the array with the initial values forgetting any change made in previous clicks.So you should put the initialization of the array/dictionary in a form load event (possibly reading from a database or a file) then you call the click event to search for the free seat, assign it to the person requesting it and save everything on the same store where you have loaded the initial values ready for the next session